# init.d script to filter command output and send to log

Tags: bash, logs, sysvinit

I wish to log `/home/michael/client`'s stdout, but wish to remove lines containing various text.  How is this accomplished?  Below is what I attempted.  Thanks

```
SCRIPT=/home/michael/client
RUNAS=michael
PIDFILE=/var/run/client.pid
LOGFILE=/var/log/client.log
PROG="Client Interface"

start() {
  if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ] && kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
    echo "$PROG already running" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo "Starting $PROG…" >&2
  local CMD="$SCRIPT   >&3 2>&1 & echo \$!"
  #local CMD="$SCRIPT  | grep -v 'Non-block' | grep -v 'Connecting with ssl...' >&3 2>&1 & echo \$!"
  cd `dirname $SCRIPT`
  su -c "$CMD" $RUNAS  3>>"$LOGFILE" >"$PIDFILE"
  #su -c "$CMD" $RUNAS  | grep -v "Non-block" | grep -v "Connecting with ssl..." 3>> "$LOGFILE" >"$PIDFILE"
  #su -c "$CMD" $RUNAS  3>> grep -v "Non-block" | grep -v "Connecting with ssl..." | "$LOGFILE" >"$PIDFILE"
  echo "$PROG started" >&2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"divide et impera"

1. are you able to write a plain bash script to do your task ?
2. then try it with *su*
3. then try it with *nohup*
4. finally try to run as a init.d script